# can't authenticate for wifi n access

Tags: wireless, authentication

Beginning about two weeks ago, perhaps owing to a software update, Network Manager has been unable to authenticate successfully on N type WiFi networks, but continues to work with other network types.

How do I debug this problem?

My system runs Ubuntu 14.10.  My hardware is a ThinkPad S1 Yoga, which uses a Intel 7260 (rev 83) wireless controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot

Comment: Through this change I gain the ability to connect to a b+g+n network, but still cannot connect to a a+n network.  So the change appears to offer an improvement but not a fix.

Comment: Does `iwlist scan` results for the a+n network show TKIP or WEP?

Comment: Following your advice, I scanned for the particular network, but it did not appear.  Further investigation revealed that the access point was malfunctioning and needed to be rebooted, solving the problem.  Therefore, it appears that your solution worked for connecting to N wireless networks.  I have searched for information about what this module options does, why it is important, and why it was unneeded as recently as a few days ago, but I have not found any good resources.  Are you able to help explain?

Comment: I can't explain why it wasn't needed a couple days ago as this parameter enables aggress TX for wireless-N and in an older kernel this was enabled by default but complaints caused the developers to disable by default.  Bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319630

Comment: You mean "TX A-MPDU aggregation"?  This feature is described as a performance optimization.  It seems mysterious that authentication fails if the flag is unset.

Comment: It happened to me on one of my laptops with the Intel Centrino Wireless-N 6250 when I switched my hotspot to wireless-N only

Comment: I am finding now that this solution works only on certain networks.  I have tried to connect to an access point operated by another party.  I am able to connect, but after a short period of time, between several seconds to several minutes, network operations begin to fail.  The connection is shown as active, but no responses are received for outgoing requests, as though no transmission is in fact ocurring.  I am wondering whether the incorrect behavoir seen before is symptomatic of a more fundamental issue yet to be resolved.  Is there any way to probe further?

Comment: do you have a firewall enabled?  UFW or GUFW?  Or TLP?

Comment: There is no firewall on client system I am describing.  The wireless network to which I am connecting sits behind a relatively permissive firewall.

Comment: After receiving a kernel update today, the problem described yesterday is resolved.  I have yet to determine whether all functionality is now available regardless of the value of the option.  Assuming full functionality is available in either case, which value will cause the aggregation optimization to occur, the default value or 8?

Comment: 8 should still enable even if you are using 3.16.0-31

Comment: Meaning I should preferably use which value, assuming it works?  Are you saying 8 is the optimal value?

Comment: 8 is usually the better option from all the posts I see and even with my own problems